# Looking for a base for a Floating Point Representation for 8/7

Tags: floating-point, precision

I am given 8/7 = 1.142857142857. . . is given, has no exact representation in a decimal floating system for B = 10 and a precision t that is finite.

Given this, is there another base, B, and some precision so that 8/7 has an exact answer.

Comment: As far as I know, decimal floating will be the closest to the exact answer for 8/7.

Comment: Um. How about base 7? No reason you couldn't have base-7 floating-point, but good luck finding an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A floating-point format using a positive integer base *B* represents a number as a sign *s* (+1 or −1), *n* digits *b*<sub>*i*</sub> (each a non-negative integer less than *B*) and an exponent *e* such that the value represented is *s* • (sum for *i* from 0 to *n*-1 of *b*<sub>*i*</sub>•*B*<sup>*i*</sup>) • *B*<sup>*e*</sup>. Since all the *b*<sub>*i*</sub> are integers, we can see this equals *S* • *B*<sup>*e*</sup> for some integer *S*.

Now suppose some such number equals 8/7, so *S* • *B*<sup>*e*</sup> = 8/7. Since *S* is an integer, *S* • *B*<sup>*e*</sup> can be 8/7 only if *e* is negative. We can rewrite the equation as *S*•7 = 8•*B*<sup>−*e*</sup>. Since *e* is negative, *B*<sup>−*e*</sup> is an integer.

The left side (*S*•7) is a multiple of 7, so the right side (8•*B*<sup>−*e*</sup>) must also be a multiple of 7. Since 7 is prime and does not divide 8, it must divide *B*<sup>−*e*</sup>. Since -*e* is positive, *B*<sup>−*e*</sup> is merely *B* multiplied by itself some number of times. Since 7 is prime, it cannot be a product of multiple factors in *B*•*B*•*B*•…, so it must be a factor of a single *B*. Therefore, *B* is a multiple of 7.

It is left as an exercise for the reader that this necessary condition is also sufficient.